can you refill zippo with Avgas?
is it possible to refuel the zippo with avgas such as 100LL or 100?
I heard gasoline can be replacement of Zippo fuel, and I got curious what about Avgas?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraethyllead#History
Read that section of this page

"is it possible to refuel the zippo with avgas": possible yes, but is it safe?

What substances one can put in a cigarette lighter is not an aviation question.

people used 97 Octane petrol for zippos as far back as WW2, including soldiers on the front lines. Good for your health? No. Worse than smoking? Probably not. 100 Octane avgas is pretty similar.

Do not in any circumstances use avgas in a lighter, to light charcoal, or for any other use where it or it's fumes may come into contact with humans or animals.
Avgas contains Tetraethyl Lead (TEL) which is toxic in a number of ways, which is why they are trying to phase it out. Don't do this.

+1, you're right, but this is to be put in perspective: Lead is dangerous, but at which concentration in air? and after how much time of exposure? We are talking about a 2 cubic cm of gazoline, not about someone living close to a road in the 60s for a couple of decades. For someone smoking and directly inhaling smoke, TEL is not the main concern, and likely not a concern at all.

TEL can be absorbed through the skin, and through inhalation. Given that someone without understanding the risks may first get it on their skin while filling their lighter, then inhale it when they light their cigarette, and may repeat that many times, I'd say it's a legitimate concern.

@mins 2mL of 100LL contains about 1 milligram of lead as TEL. That's enough to bring the interior of a compact car (for example) to several times the allowed limit for industrial workers who work with the stuff.

@mins Exhaust emissions decline roughly as 1/r^3. With a lighter, you're inhaling most to all of the lead, versus a much smaller amount with reasonable distance.

@Chris: Your example must be adjusted to the smoker context. At a rate of one lighter refilling per month --> divide 2 ml by 30 for a day. Smokers don't fill their 6-liter lungs with gasoline vapor, but maybe with 90% of fresh air --> divide by 10. For the exposure time, say 20*2s=40s a day vs. 8 hours in your worker example, divide by 720. The time x concentration ratio for lighting 20 cigarettes a day with 100LL is only 1/200 000 of the one in your car example (so likely legally allowed). Not claiming a scientific demo, only rough figures for a raw comparison.

@mins The TEL in the lighter is enough to bring the whole car up to several times the limit for the whole day. Using the lighter in close proximity to their face means they're going to be inhaling rather more of it than if it were evenly distributed throughout the air of the car they were in. In 8 hours, you breathe in roughly 2 cubic meters of air- corresponding to about 150 micrograms of TEL at the legal limit. Or 1/7 what's in the lighter. Plausible for a heavy smoker to go through in a day.

he asks if it's possible, not if it's safe :)

also, will it kill you before the smoking does? Probably not.
